# Should [jade] be renamed to [pug]?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The [jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jade) templating language has been renamed to [pug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pug).  I can't find a way to rename the tag though: https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/24898

Comment: A tag merge is more in order then, given that the tag [tag:pugjs] already exists.

Comment: Is there anything in [pug] that isn't in [jade]? Should there be two tags or two tags merged?

Comment: Definitely merged.  Pug is the same language under a new name.  It does have new features, but they are incremental changes.

Comment: What do I need to do to make this happen?  I maintain the templating engine that this tag is for, so I don't think there should be any debate as to whether this is the right course of action.